# regular expression for corresponding bracket/parentheses types

Tags: python, regex, regex-group, python-re

**tl;dr** among bracket/parentheses characters `<`, `(`, `{`, `[` only match the corresponding `>` or `)` or `}` or `]` within *one* regular expression pattern.

Using Python, I want to match corresponding bracket/parentheses types.

For example, using [`re.fullmatch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.fullmatch) these would return matches

```
<abc>
(foo bar)
{blarg}
```

and these would *not* return matches

```
 <abc)
 (foo bar]
 {blarg>
```

- I want one regular expression pattern (i.e. one call to `re.fullmatch`) instead of several.
- I do not want repeated regular expression patterns within one string (see **@zvone** refining attempt using `|`, e.g. `<.*>|{.*}|…`).

**Overall, I would like to write something relatively simple like**:

```
(?<brackets>\<\[\({)outrageously complicated re pattern(?<bracket_corresponding_to_earlier_brackets_group>)
```

The Python idiom of [backreference to a named group](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) is in the area of what I'm looking for. I need something like a "*mapped backreference to a named group*" or "*corresponsing backreference to a named group*" (I made up those phrases).

Comment: Perhaps using a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) for example `<[^>]+>` https://regex101.com/r/AO2SVH/1 If you are looking for to capture all the chars in a capturing group and then refer to that group you will not get a closing match as the closing brackets are all different characters.

Comment: Couple of _IF'S_:  If Python re did conditional constructs (regex does), and a very large part of the regex made up the body, i.e. between brackets, then this is how you'd do it `(?s)(?:(<)|(\()|({)|(\[)).*?(?(1)>|(?(2)\)|(?(3)}|(?(4)\]|(?!)))))`

Answer (score 1):

You can't use back-reference to match `(` to `)`. You just have to match it explicitly.

For example, this will match something within `<` and `>`:

```
r'<.*>'
```

This will match something within `[` and `]`:

```
r'\[.*\]'
```

To match either of them, use `|`, which means *or*:

```
r'(<.*>)|({.*})|(\(.*\))|(\[.*\])'
```

Comment: That does work per my request.  hmm... I was hoping for code where I could define a set of bracket characters once, e.g. `[(\[{<]` and not have to repeat any patterns so tediously.  Thanks for the help.  Let me adjust my question.

Comment: @JamesThomasMoon1979 This the way to do it with regex. You can have a utility function to help construct the regex, or you can use something other than regex, but if you use regex, you basically have to do this.